# how can i multiple context state handle in screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

how can i multiple context state handle in screen?

```
 const { state } = useContext(profileContext);
 const { state,AttendanceInGetByDate } = useContext(AttendanceContax);
```

Comment: state as `somethingElse` ?

Comment: don't understand

Comment: `{ state as someOthername } = useContext(profileContext);`
`someOthername.something`

Comment: it's syntax error

Answer (score 1):

You can rename properties while destructuring:

```
const { state: profileDAta } = useContext(profileContext);
const { state: attendanceData, AttendanceInGetByDate } = useContext(AttendanceContax);
```

There are a lot of articles on destructuring in Javascript, it's kind of hype recently([one of them](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/)), choose any.

Moreover you don't have to use destructuring with hooks if that creates any inconvenience to you:

```
const profile = useContext(profileContext);
const attendance = useContext(AttendanceContax);
...
// here you can refer to profile.state and attendance.state independently
```